# Yii2 и Яндекс Касса

Tags: php, yii2, яндекс-касса

Три часа борюсь с яндекс кассой. Саппорт говорит  что у меня сайт не принимает POST запросы и возвращает `bad request #400`. Сайт на Yii2. Есть предположение что это из за ckrf токена. Может быть кто-то сталкивался и сможет мне помочь?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В контроллере реализуйте метод **beforeAction** таким образом.

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
   $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
   return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Если не хотите отключать **CSRF** для всех действий, то можете отключить для определенных действий:

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
   if ($action->id === 'test') $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
   return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

В данном случае мы отключили **CSRF** для действия **test**

Comment: А так можете опробовать расширение: https://github.com/Mirocow/yii2-yandex-maps

Comment: Действительно помогло. Отключил для контроллера.

Answer (score 0):

Для нескольких экшенов:

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
    $this->enableCsrfValidation = !in_array($action->id, ['check', 'aviso']);
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```